# Repair moved Visual Studio directory

Tags: visual-studio

I merged my partitioned HDD and had to move the Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate installation folder manually between the partitions, along with some other applications. Something went wrong when moving Visual Studio and now I can no longer run it.

Whenever I try to open Visual studio this pops up:

[image: Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall the application.]

Trying to uninstall gives me this message:

[image: Setup engine Element not found.]

A repair results in this:

[image: Fatal error during installation.]

I have also tried to just remove the folder from Program Files to try and get a clean install but there wasn't any install button in the setup. (only repair/modify/uninstall)

Is there a way to manually tell Visual studio that these files are just moved or is it possible to remove Visual studio completely and run a new setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question for future readers.

I fixed it by splitting the disk again and moving the folder to it's original directory. That way I could uninstall Visual Studio from "D:/" and reinstall it on "C:/".